# Deleting Rows with MySQL with other values for 1 column

Tags: mysql

This is a simple one but one that I can't seem to figure out. I want to run a query like this but it only leaves records with month as 10 and year as 2016. Where am I going wrong that months 7, 8  and 9 aren't also staying in the database.

Thanks again guys.

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE year != 2016 AND ((month != 7) AND (month != 8) AND (month != 9) AND (month != 10))
```

Comment: You have to use the OR: `DELETE FROM tableA WHERE year != 2016 AND ((month != 7) OR (month != 8) OR (month != 9) OR (month != 10))`

Comment: So you want to delete everything other than months 7, 8, 9, 10 in year 2016?

Comment: Yes I do. I have figured it now but it was a bit of a botch job to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone for helping but I managed to fix it by running two queries. Not ideal but it worked.

The first was:

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE year != 2016
```

Then I ran:

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE month < 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I would run

```
DELETE FROM referrals
WHERE year <> 2016 
AND (month < 7 OR month > 10)
```

I'd suggest using the diamond operator (<>) in favor of != as the first one is valid SQL and the second one is a MySQL addition.

Comment: can you post an example of the DB before running the delete instruction?

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks again. I managed to fix it by running two queries. First was Delete everything that wasn't in 2016 and then delete everything less than 7. It seemed to work fine.